# How to swap card content without converting to text/plain with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing trello like application.

For now I have a dashboard of cards which I can swap, drag&drop and move around. I found this piece of code online. So everything worked fine until I formatted the card content(added button, bold text etc.). And now the problem is with swapping the cards, because the function only swaps `text/plain` so after swapping, the card content converts to plain text.

I tried changing the data type of the swapped object etc, nothing really worked. How could I fix that?

I'm not really familiar with js, that's why I'm asking for help, tried googling first but none of my solutions worked.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function dragStart(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", ev.target.id);
}

function dropIt(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  let sourceId = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
  let sourceIdEl = document.getElementById(sourceId);
  let sourceIdParentEl = sourceIdEl.parentElement;
  let targetEl = document.getElementById(ev.target.id)
  let targetParentEl = targetEl.parentElement;

  if (targetParentEl.id !== sourceIdParentEl.id) {
    if (targetEl.className === sourceIdEl.className) {
      targetParentEl.appendChild(sourceIdEl);
    } else {
      targetEl.appendChild(sourceIdEl);

    }

  } else {
    let holder = targetEl;
    let holderText = holder.textContent;
    targetEl.textContent = sourceIdEl.textContent;
    sourceIdEl.textContent = holderText;
    holderText = '';
  }

}
```

Comment: You're only dragging the ID of the element, so `text/plain` is appropriate. The problem is likely the `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` in the `else` branch.

Comment: @HereticMonkey wow, nice, that work, thank you for quick fix!